# How to apply a function to a subset of data, where the subset is specified by another data.table?

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I have a data.table l1 with three columns, Minute, Posixct for time and group_cor for my value, and I would like to calculate the number of unique values of group_cor in certain time intervals based on data.table s1. In my original dataset I have about 1 500 000 data rows lasting approximately 12 days (structured as l1) so I am looking for a fast method to go through all this data.

```
       Posixct            group_cor   Minute
 1: 2017-08-11 13:31:36       185     2017-08-11 13:31:00
 2: 2017-08-11 13:31:36       185     2017-08-11 13:31:00
 3: 2017-08-11 13:31:36       185     2017-08-11 13:31:00
 4: 2017-08-11 13:31:37       186     2017-08-11 13:31:00
 5: 2017-08-11 13:31:37       186     2017-08-11 13:31:00
 6: 2017-08-11 13:31:37       187     2017-08-11 13:31:00
 7: 2017-08-11 13:31:37       187     2017-08-11 13:31:00
 8: 2017-08-11 13:31:37       187     2017-08-11 13:31:00
 9: 2017-08-11 13:31:37       187     2017-08-11 13:31:00
```

This is s1 where the start indicates the start of the time interval and end the end of it. Each time interval is one minute and this window is mooved along 1 second at a time.

```
                     start                 end
  1: 2017-08-11 13:31:36 2017-08-11 13:32:36
  2: 2017-08-11 13:31:37 2017-08-11 13:32:37
  3: 2017-08-11 13:31:38 2017-08-11 13:32:38
  4: 2017-08-11 13:31:39 2017-08-11 13:32:39
  5: 2017-08-11 13:31:40 2017-08-11 13:32:40
```

I have tried using data.table to add a column No to the data.table s1 where I use the "on" argument to specify the time window.

```
oma <- function(x) length(unique(x))
s1[ l1, No:=oma(group_cor), on=c('start<Posixct','end>=Posixct')]
```

However, this gives

```
> s1
               start                 end      No
  1: 2017-08-11 13:31:36 2017-08-11 13:32:36 188
  2: 2017-08-11 13:31:37 2017-08-11 13:32:37 188
  3: 2017-08-11 13:31:38 2017-08-11 13:32:38 188
  4: 2017-08-11 13:31:39 2017-08-11 13:32:39 188
  5: 2017-08-11 13:31:40 2017-08-11 13:32:40 188
```

The No column is 188 for all the time windows, which is not true (and I dont know where this value comes from..)

```
> range(s1$No)
 [1] 188 188
```

I know the amount of unique values for each minute and the new No should be similar to them

```
> tapply(l1$group_cor, l1$Minute,oma)
2017-08-11 13:31:00 2017-08-11 13:32:00 2017-08-11 13:33:00 2017-08-11     13:34:00 
             11                  17                  18                  17 
2017-08-11 13:35:00 2017-08-11 13:36:00 2017-08-11 13:37:00 2017-08-11 13:38:00 
             21                  22                  23                  22 
2017-08-11 13:39:00 2017-08-11 13:40:00 
             20                  22
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be highly appreciated! Also suggestions to how I could do this in another way.. Thank you very much.

Comment: I think maybe you need a `by=.EACHI` in your join, otherwise it just counts using the full `group_cor` vector in the join. Btw, `oma` is in data.table as `uniqueN` already.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and pointing out `uniqueN`. I tried running `s1[ l, No:=uniqueN(group_cor), on=c('start<Posixct','end>=Posixct'), by=.EACHI]`  But I don´t get the right answer. I get no all the values in column `No`as 1. What is it doing now?

Comment: I never figured the pure data.table solution out but ended up using  `d <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(s1)),function(n) {
    a <- l1[Posixct > s1$start[n] & Posixct <= s1$end[n],
                .(No = uniqueN(group_cor))]
  })`  and adding the list `d` (after I converted it to vector) to the data.table `s1`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly and which is what Frank mentioned in the comments, you are looking for

```
intvl[dat, cnt := uniqueN(group_cor), by=.EACHI, on=c('start<Posixct','end>=Posixct')][, 
   cnt := replace(cnt, is.na(cnt), 0L)]
```

output:

```
                 start                 end cnt
1: 2017-08-11 13:31:36 2017-08-11 13:32:36   1
2: 2017-08-11 13:31:37 2017-08-11 13:32:37   0
3: 2017-08-11 13:31:38 2017-08-11 13:32:38   0
4: 2017-08-11 13:31:39 2017-08-11 13:32:39   0
5: 2017-08-11 13:31:40 2017-08-11 13:32:40   0
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
dat <- fread("Posixct,group_cor,Minute
2017-08-11 13:31:36,185,2017-08-11 13:31:00
2017-08-11 13:31:36,185,2017-08-11 13:31:00
2017-08-11 13:31:36,185,2017-08-11 13:31:00
2017-08-11 13:31:37,186,2017-08-11 13:31:00
2017-08-11 13:31:37,186,2017-08-11 13:31:00
2017-08-11 13:31:37,187,2017-08-11 13:31:00
2017-08-11 13:31:37,187,2017-08-11 13:31:00
2017-08-11 13:31:37,187,2017-08-11 13:31:00
2017-08-11 13:31:37,187,2017-08-11 13:31:00")
cols <- c("Posixct", "Minute")
dat[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, as.POSIXct, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), .SDcols=cols]

intvl <- fread("start,end
2017-08-11 13:31:36,2017-08-11 13:32:36
2017-08-11 13:31:37,2017-08-11 13:32:37
2017-08-11 13:31:38,2017-08-11 13:32:38
2017-08-11 13:31:39,2017-08-11 13:32:39
2017-08-11 13:31:40,2017-08-11 13:32:40")
cols <- c("start", "end")
intvl[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, as.POSIXct, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), .SDcols=cols]
```

I think you couldn't get it previously is because you had too many different variables in your R session. It would help to restart the session and use a clean data and interval.

Comment: I ran `s1[l1, cnt := uniqueN(group_cor), by=.EACHI, on=c('start<Posixct','end>=Posixct')][,cnt := replace(cnt, is.na(cnt), 0L)]` on the data but do not get the output what I want. The output looks like this                 `start                 end cnt
1: 2017-08-11 13:31:36 2017-08-11 13:32:36   1
2: 2017-08-11 13:31:37 2017-08-11 13:32:37   1
3: 2017-08-11 13:31:38 2017-08-11 13:32:38   1
4: 2017-08-11 13:31:39 2017-08-11 13:32:39   1
5: 2017-08-11 13:31:40 2017-08-11 13:32:40   1
6: 2017-08-11 13:31:41 2017-08-11 13:32:41   1`

Comment: And the range of values is from 1 to 1 `range(s1$cnt)
[1] 1 1`

Comment: The output I would like to have looks like this `start                 end cnt
                                  1: 2017-08-11 13:31:36 2017-08-11 13:32:36  22
2: 2017-08-11 13:31:37 2017-08-11 13:32:37  20
3: 2017-08-11 13:31:38 2017-08-11 13:32:38  20
4: 2017-08-11 13:31:39 2017-08-11 13:32:39  21
5: 2017-08-11 13:31:40 2017-08-11 13:32:40  21
6: 2017-08-11 13:31:41 2017-08-11 13:32:41  20` I can get this output when I use the lapply method I wrote about before but when I ran it on the original dataset it is taking hours.Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: In the output I would like, the `cnt`values should range from 15 to 24. They do when I use the lapply method                `unique(s1$cnt)
 [1] 22 20 21 19 18 17 16 15 23 24`

Comment: In the output you show @chinsoon12 the first line should have a `cnt`value of `3` instead of `1` because `group_cor`values 185,186 and 187 are present in this time interval `2017-08-11 13:31:36 2017-08-11 13:32:36`. The next line should have a `cnt`value `2`because only `group_cor`values 186 and 187 are present in time interval `2017-08-11 13:31:37 2017-08-11 13:32:37`. The rest of the time intervals are out of range (I have only showed you a small portion of the data). Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: how do you get cnt=3 for the first row if you are using `start<Posixct`?

Comment: Sorry - the line should be `start<=Posixct`